# phpMailer check if field is empty

Tags: database, email, phpmailer, isset

I have a reservation script, wich runs fine and puts stuff in the database. However, when I want the administrator to send an e-mail whenever a reservation has been put, I'd like to leave the e-mail blank when the user hasn't filled it in.

For example, the user puts in his name, e-mail, date and so on, but leaves the fields last name and comments blank, I don't want that to be outputted in the e-mail.

I've tried

```
if(isset($_POST['Lastname'])){ 
    $Lastname=$_POST['Lastname'];
} else {
    $Lastname="The user didn't input his lastname";
}
```

I've tried the same this with empty().

I know this is the way, but I don't know where to put it.

Here's my code.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {      
    include('../../../wp-config.php');          
        $Naam=$_POST['Naam'];
        $Achternaam=$_POST['Achternaam'];
        $Omgeving=$_POST['Omgeving'];
        $Geslacht=$_POST['Geslacht'];
        $Bedrijfsnaam=$_POST['Bedrijfsnaam'];
        $Postcode=$_POST['Postcode'];
        $Adres=$_POST['Adres'];
        $Woonplaats=$_POST['Woonplaats'];
        $Teloverdag=$_POST['Teloverdag'];
        $Teldirect=$_POST['Teldirect'];
        $Email=$_POST['Email'];
        $Aantal=$_POST['Aantal'];
        $Datum=$_POST['Datum'];
        $Vanuur=$_POST['Vanuur'];
        $Vanminuut=$_POST['Vanminuut'];
        $Totuur=$_POST['Totuur'];
        $Totminuut=$_POST['Totminuut'];
        $Opmerkingen=$_POST['Opmerkingen'];
        $Nieuwsbrief=$_POST['Nieuwsbrief'];
        $Datumverzonden=$_POST['Datumverzonden'];
        $Status=$_POST['Status'];

if (!$error) {

            require_once('phpMailer/class.phpmailer.php');
            $mail = new PHPMailer();

            $mail->From = $email;
            $mail->FromName = $name;
            $mail->Subject = "Website Reserveringsformulier Form";
            $mail->AddAddress($site_owners_email, $site_owners_name);
            $mail->AddAddress('mail@gmail.com', 'Name');
            $mail->IsHTML(true);
            $mail->Body = "<font size='5'>Beste Zomerlust</font>" . "\r\n<br /><br /> " . "Er is een reservering geplaats via restaurantzomerlust.nl." . "\r\n<br /><br />";
            $mail->Body .= "<b>Naam: </b>" . $Naam . "\r\n<br />";
            $mail->Body .= "<b>Achternaam: </b>" . $Achternaam . "\r\n<br />";
            $mail->Body .= "<b>E-mail: </b>" . $Email . "\r\n<br /><br />";
            $mail->Body .= "<b>Reservering: </b>" . $Omgeving . "\r\n<br /><br />";
            $mail->Body .= "<b>Aanhef: </b>" . $Geslacht . "\r\n<br /><br />";
            $mail->Body .= "<b>Bedrijfsnaam: </b>" . $Bedrijfsnaam . "\r\n<br />";
            $mail->Body .= "<b>Postcode: </b>" . $Postcode . "\r\n<br />";
            $mail->Body .= "<b>Adres: </b>" . $Adres . "\r\n<br />";
            $mail->Body .= "<b>Woonplaats: </b>" . $Woonplaats . "\r\n<br /><br />";
            $mail->Body .= "<b>Tel. overdag: </b>" . $Teloverdag . "\r\n<br />";
            $mail->Body .= "<b>Tel. direct: </b>" . $Teldirect . "\r\n<br /><br />";
            $mail->Body .= "<b>Aantal persronen: </b>" . $Aantal . "\r\n<br />";
            $mail->Body .= "<b>Datum: </b>" . $Datum . "\r\n<br />";
            $mail->Body .= "<b>Van: </b>" . $Vanuur . ":" . $Vanminuut . " tot " . $Totuur . ":" . $Totminuut . "\r\n<br /><br />";
            $mail->Body .= "<b>Opmerkingen: </b>" . $Opmerkingen . "\r\n<br /><br />";
            $mail->Body .= "<b>Nieuwsbrief: </b>" . $Nieuwsbrief . "\r\n<br />";

$mail->Send();


        } # end if no error
        else {

        }
```

And one little other thing: Whenever the email has been send, the data is also stored in a database. What can I do to achieve the same effect for the database. So if nothing is set, the data should be "Nothing set" or something.

I hope you guys understand.

Answer (score 0):

what about

```
if(isset($_POST['Lastname'])){ 
    $Lastname=$_POST['Lastname'];
} else if ($_POST['Lastname'] == ''){
    $Lastname="The user didn't input his lastname";
}else{
    $Lastname="The user didn't input his lastname";
}
```